# How to show yii2 database relation in view

Tags: model-view-controller, yii2

I am new in yii2. I don't know much about table relation. I have a 3 tables shops promotions and promotion_details. promotion_details contains promotion id and shop id. promotion has status like active or inactive. i want display in shop view only active promotions. How can i Do that? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In  you promotion_detail view  add  a getter  function for relation and a getter function for the field

```
/* ActiveRelation */
public function getPropomition()
{
   return $this->hasOne(Promotion::className(), ['id' => 'promotion_id']);
}

/* Getter for status name */
public function getStatus() {
   return $this->prpmotion->status;
}
```

in  view

```
echo GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'filterModel' => $searchModel,
    'columns' => [
        ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
        'id',
        .......
        'status',
        ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
    ]
]);
```

this guide could be useful http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/621/filter-sort-by-calculated-related-fields-in-gridview-yii-2-0/

Comment: @RAHULVENNEERS   if my answer is what you are looking for .. please mark it as accepted .. otherwise  .. ask me ..