# How to get data from not directly related tables and use it on gridview with modelSearch() Yii2

Tags: php, yii, yii2

I have 3 classes Persona, Alumno and factura. i need to show the person fullname  on factura view using the gridview and the search function. The fullname is in Persona. Factura is only related to alumno through id_alumno and alumno is related to persona through id_persona.
i try to solved this by creating a new variable fullname and a function to get persona on class factura.

```
class Factura extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord{
     public $full_name;
}

public static function tableName()
{
    return 'factura';
}

public function rules()
{
return [
  [['id_factura_reemplazo', 'id_obra_social', 'id_alumno',], 'integer'],
  [['id_obra_social', 'id_alumno'], 'required'],
  [['fecha_factura','fullname','id_persona'], 'safe'],
];
}

public function attributeLabels()
{
return [
  'id_factura' => 'Id Factura',
  'id_factura_reemplazo' => 'Id Factura Reemplazo',
  'id_obra_social' => 'Id Obra Social',
  'id_alumno' => 'Id Alumno',
  'fullName'=>Yii::t('app', 'Nombre y Apellido'),
  ];
}

public function getIdAlumno()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Alumno::className(), ['id_alumno' => 'id_alumno']);
}

public function getIdPersona() {
   return $this->hasOne(Persona::className(), ['id_persona' => 'id_persona'])
   ->via('idAlumno');
}

public function getFullname(){
  if($this->idPersona)
     return $this->idPersona->nombre." ".$this->idPersona->apellido;
  return null;
}
```

I get:
Invalid Call – yii\base\InvalidCallException

Setting read-only property: app\models\Facturasearch::fullName

```
 if (method_exists($this, 'get' . $name)) {
        throw new InvalidCallException('Setting read-only property: ' .       get_class($this) . '::' . $name);
    } else {
        throw new UnknownPropertyException('Setting unknown property: ' . get_class($this) . '::' . $name);
    }
```

it's like it doesnt have the getter... the problem jump from the line when it tries to do $this->load($params);

```
class Facturasearch extends Factura{    
public function rules()
{
    return [
        [['id_factura', 'id_factura_reemplazo',  'id_alumno', 'numero'], 'integer'],
        [['id_obra_social','fecha_factura', 'observacion','id_alumno','fullName','id_persona'], 'safe'],
    ];
}
public function scenarios()
{
    // bypass scenarios() implementation in the parent class
    return Model::scenarios();
}
public function search($params)
{
    $query = Factura::find();

    $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' => $query,
    ]);

    $this->load($params);
    ...
```

Comment: take a look  at this  .. answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38994984/how-to-show-yii2-database-relation-in-view

Comment: it's what i use, but my problem goes beyond that.

Comment: I'm sorry i haven't  take a deep look at your question .. but the error seems related  to the search function ... when /where you have the error  .. whe you call the related controller/action or after the gridview is showed  when you filter for a search?

Comment: Anyway i have posted  a first suggestion ... hope is useful

Comment: Update your question and add all the code for function search in FacturaSearch Model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add a pubblic var in FacturaSearch for fullname

```
class Facturasearch extends Factura{  

  public $fullname;


  public function rules()
  {
      return [
          [['id_factura', 'id_factura_reemplazo',  'id_alumno', 'numero'], 'integer'],
          [['id_obra_social','fecha_factura', 'observacion','id_alumno','fullName','id_persona'], 'safe'],
      ];
  }
  public function scenarios()
  {
      // bypass scenarios() implementation in the parent class
      return Model::scenarios();
  }
  public function search($params)
  {
      $query = Factura::find();

      $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
          'query' => $query,
      ]);

      $this->load($params);
      ...
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort scaisEdge, but i still get the same error. I added a public $fullname on the factura model too, but no luck.

Comment: i am sory, I don't understand what you are saying. I put it just like your answer and i doesnt work.

Comment: You have tell that you have added  $fullname in factura model .. .. my answer is don't add the $fullmodel in factura model  because you have the getFullname function for this  .. you should add $fullname only in facturaSearch model  ... but you could add all the code for function search  ..and the code  for controller/action (related  to your view with grid) ?